# design pattern for describing a variable subpart of a config file

Tags: java, design-patterns, idioms

Suppose I have an XML *config* file like the following:

```
<myapp>
    <settings/>

    <output>

        <mailto>mail service configuration parameters</mailto>
                           OR            
        <smsto>sms service configuration parameters</smsto>        

    <output>
```

While the settings node will have always the same structure, the output node may have different structures, depending on whether it is a mail or an SMS output.

The Java classes will be:

```
class MyAppConfig {

    String settingXXX;

    {what type?} output;

}
```

Obviously I will have a `class MailTo {}` and a `class SmsTo {}`.

Since output may either be a `MailTo` or a `SmsTo` object, it can be:

- an Object type, since `MailTo` and `SmsTo` don't have any superclass in
  common.
- an `Output` interface, that in turn is implemented by MailTo and
  SmsTo. Since `MailTo` and `SmsTo` don't have anything in common, `Output` interface will be empty and will "collapse" to a marker interface.

I think that, given this situation, this is the only implementation possible. 
The client code will typecast `Object` or `Output` to `MailTo` or `SmsTo`, that must be handled differently.

Nevertheless, I'm puzzled because design patterns (GoF book) seem not consider this kind of situations. 
What is the "real world" pattern that you would apply in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I think the direction should be a **Creational Pattern**, page 33 in GoF book presents a help table for building a variable design. From the page:

```
Design Pattern         Aspect(s) That Can Vary
--------------         -----------------------
Abstract Factory (68)  families of product objects
Builder (75)           how a composite object gets created
Factory Method (83)    subclass of object that is instantiated
Prototype (91)         class of object that is instantiated
```

From this table, **Prototype** seems to fit the best it basically lets you to

> specify the kinds of objects to create using a prototypical instance, and create new objects by copying this prototype.

EDIT: nice detailed info here: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype

Please elaborate on your problem if this design is not enough...

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks like a textbook example of the benefits of polymorphism, I don't think there is a named pattern to implement this functionality as this is a fairly basic OO principle.  Your idea to create an interface for both classes to implement is the best idea allowing you to call myInterface.doStuff to handle both types of communication and allow for more to be added if necessary.

Comment: I don't think so. Perhaps the example is not clear in showing that MailTo and SmsTo have nothing in common but being a "output". The essence of polymorphism is to use an interface or a superclass and let the implementors decide the exact behavior of an inherited method. In those cases, programming to an "interface" is perfect. BUT the most the common aspects between the two classes are few, the more likely you will need to deal with specific aspects of your class. At the end of the line, we have an empty interface that contains no methods. How can you use polymorphism?

Comment: As I understand your question, you have an App that is intended to send a communication(s) to someone. MailTo and SmsTo are related in that they are your methods of communication; this is all the relation they need. I am more familiar with .NET where creating an interface called 'communication' with a method called 'send' for both classes to implement would be the best solution, so both classes can be held in the same collection of type communication, this might not be possible in java, but a class with a virtual method would achieve the same but less extensible result.

Comment: the factory pattern would be a good way of creating the classes as need though as kevin junghans suggested.

Comment: Factory pattern is very useful when the set of possible implementors of an interface is "open-ended", and reveals to be quite burdensome when you have two or three or even ten implementors classes, but being the set unlikely to be extended. I think that this would be "push in" the factory pattern, so you feel the code is "right" because it respects a DP. But factory pattern pays for itself only when the set of classes is growing. A situation that occurs often in frameworks, not so often in common applications.

Comment: The factory pattern is not just used when "possible implementors of an interface is open-ended." It also used when a specific object interface can implement more than one class of objects and knowing which class is not necessary. It is also used for dependency injection.  And saying you can predict when the "set of classes will grow" is like saying your application will never evolve.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Ryathal](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/131409/22493) that this is basic polymorphism and therefore you will not find a design pattern for it.  Although you could use something like a factory pattern to create the appropriate class based on the configuration settings.  I disagree that the email and sms service do not have anything in common.  The base class could be something like "communications service" and these services would always have a location for the service (ex: smtp server location or url for web service or API) and some credentials for authentication.  The "email" class and "sms" class would inherit from the "communications service" class.  The method for sending a message would differ in the derived classes.

Comment: Maybe I haven't been clear on the fact that i am not looking for an explanation on polymorphism, but i'm trying to create an example (perhaps insufficient)that shows a "difficult" application of polymorphism. I've choosen two "systems", mail and sms that are rather different. You can say that there is something in common, but as long as there is something that is different, polymorphism will be lame. If I send an email the text can be long, while an sms should be short. So while they are both "output" methods, but they have neither the sendText(String text) in common. The caller should decide.

Comment: That depends on your level of granularity. If the interface method was sendOutput(String).....

Comment: I have implemented a notification system using polymorphism in just this manner.  It had even more communications channels such as voice and IM.  Also the SMS and voice might use different services that had different API's.  This was all encapsulated beautifully in an abstract class that had one method called sendMessage.  I used the factory DP to create the instances of these objects. The class that handled going through the list of contacts did not care what the destination service was, it just needed to send a message and get a response. I think you picked a bad example of difficult poly.

Comment: @Martijn Verburg:If the name was different? :-) The problem is that in polymorphism the "low-level-class" decides. Instead, here i am showing that the client of the class should have some level of awareness of the type of implementation because it (and not the implementor) should take certain decisions.

Comment: @Kevin Junghans. Maybe, picking examples is always difficult :-). What if the message itself is different among different channels? What would be the abstract class in that case?

Comment: The notification system I previously mentioned had different messages for different channels and could have different messages for same channels.  The abstract class would still have a single method called sendMessage and it accepts two parameters; the address to send the message to (ex: phone number, email address, IM user name) and a unique ID for the message to send.  This method pulled the message from a database and build it because it might have variable info (ex: Hi [Kevin], this is a message from...).  So the abstract class also had helper methods to build the message before sending.